# Вызов перегруженного метода в asp.net mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Добрый день. Пытаюсь написать контролер в проекте **mvc 5** с перегруженным методом. Задача состоит в вводе значения в поле, и выводе информации, содержаний это значение из репозитария в перегруженном методе.

При вводе значения в поле выдается ошибка:

> Текущий запрос для действия "SearchForGift" на контроллере типа
>   "GiftController" является неоднозначным на следующих методах действий:
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult SearchForGift(System.String) на типе
>   NewYearGifts.WebUI.Controllers.GiftController
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult SearchForGift(System.String, Int32) на типе
>   NewYearGifts.WebUI.Controllers.GiftController).

Спасибо за помощь.

*GiftController(контроллер)*

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult SearchForGift()
{
    return View(repository.Gifts);

}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SearchForGift(string searchTerm)
{
    return View(repository.Gifts.Where(g => g.Name.StartsWith(searchTerm)));
}
```

*SearchForGift.cshtml(поле с представлением)*

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("SearchForGift", "Gift", FormMethod.Post)) 
{
    <b>Name: </b>
    @Html.TextBox("searchTerm", null, new { id = "txtSearch" })
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
}
```

Comment: `SearchForGift(System.String, Int32)` - где?

Answer (score 1):

В контроллере должно быть два метода с одинаковым названием, к одному из них должен быть применен атрибут `[HttpGet]`, к другому `[HttpPost]`.

В вашем случае в контроллере видно два метода `SearchForGift()` и `SearchForGift(string searchTerm)`, но также в ошибке есть еще и третий `SearchForGift(System.String, Int32)`

**Вариант 1**

Ошибку можно исправить переименовав третий метод.

**Вариант 2**

Еще можно объединить методы `SearchForGift(System.String)` и `SearchForGift(System.String, Int32)` в один

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SearchForGift(string searchTerm, int? param)
{
    if (param == null)
    {
        //поиск по параметру searchTerm
        var model = repository.Gifts.Where(g => g.Name.StartsWith(searchTerm));
        return View(model);
    }
    else
    {
        //поиск по двум параметрам
        var model = repository.Gifts.Where(g => g.Name.StartsWith(searchTerm)
            && p => p.Id == param);
        return View(model);
    }
}
```